# How to show current position of the dragging item

Tags: react-beautiful-dnd

How to show the current position of the dragging item, in react-beautiful-dnd.

something like decreasing the opacity of the item

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/draggable.md#2-snapshot-draggablestatesnapshot](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/draggable.md#extending-draggableprops-style)

There is shown how to get the current state of the draggable item.

"The children function is also provided with a small amount of state relating to the current drag state. This can be optionally used to enhance your component. A common use case is changing the appearance of a  while it is being dragged."